# T-Hub Shipping tracking number not pairing with order

Tags: magento2.2.2, shipment-tracking

I have Magento 2.2.2 and T-Hub for shipping.  In version 1.9, T-Hub would send the shipping tracking number directly to the "Shipment" file.  Both the product detail and the tracker would appear together.  Now with version 2.2.2, the tracking number comes over, but does not merge with the product detail (see below).  I now have to copy the tracker number and hit the "Ship" button and manually past the tracker into a second shipment.  Has anyone experienced this and have you been able to resolve the issue so once the tracker is created in T-Hub, it get sent to the shipper in Magento and associated to the product order detail?

[image]

[image]